# For-loop that is skipping even count

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a small `for` loop, but it is skipping even count , what am I missing ?

```js
var i = 0;
function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //code below
        console.log(Date() + ' and count is ' + i++);
        //code above
        if (i < 20) {
            myLoop();
        }
    }, i++)
}
myLoop()
```

Comment: You have 2 `i++` in your code... (also not a single `for` loop)

Comment: the i++ in the console.log should not affect the outcome, or should it ? even when removed, the counter does 5 runs only.

Comment: Why not? It increments `i` just the same. So your code ends up incrementing `i` twice every time you call `myLoop`

Comment: then change it to `console.log(... + (i+1))` so it doesn't increment twice.

Comment: you are correct, one would assume that console.log is more of a display command and would not do such.
but when changing it to i+1, it does not display the correct count

Comment: `console.log` is a normal function, it doesn't have any special properties that would prevent it from executing side effects of expressions

Comment: UnholySheep please post an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `i++` in the `console.log` statement is **modifying** your `i` variable.

`i++` is equal to `i = i + 1`.

Replace `i++` with `i`, which will evaluate correctly as postfix increment will return the value *before* the modification which would just be `i`.

This works:

```js
var i = 0;

function myLoop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //code below
    console.log(Date() + ' and count is ' + i);
    //code above
    if (i < 20) {
      myLoop();
    }
  }, i++)
}
myLoop()
```

Comment: It should really be just `i` instead of `i + 1` in order to have the same output as OPs intended original code, since postfix increment will return the value *before* the modification

Comment: @UnholySheep Very good point, updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

i++ is equal i = i + 1; But when you call console.log(i++), first thing wil be console.log with Old value, and after increment your value.

Answer (score 0):

You raise the timeout with every iteration by on millisecond. Is that what you wanted?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)

```
var i = 0;
function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //code below
        console.log(Date() + ' and count is ' + i++);
        //code above
        if (i < 20) {
            myLoop();
        }
    }, 1)
}
myLoop()
```

Comment: i will multiply i++ by 1000 to add one second or 2000 to add 2 seconds, that is the goal.

Comment: than instead of 1 write i*1000. i*1000 will not change the value of i. i++ is i = i + 1. i*1000 is an anonymous value

Comment: This script is using the i for 2 reasons, one for time increment and for count. so i cannot write i*1000 for that will display the count in 000s instead of the real count.
I am using the 2nd variable and working on the script .

Comment: No it doesn't. i*1000, i*1000000000000000 or i*i doesn't change the value of i!

Comment: var i = 0;
var t = 0;
function myLoop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //code below
    console.log(Date() + ' and count is ' + t++);
    //code above
    if (t < 20) {
      myLoop();
    }
  }, ((i++)*1000))
}
myLoop()

//try it yourself

Comment: I don't have to, cause (i++)*1000 is unequal i*1000.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done by adding another variable for the console.log

```js
var i = 0;
var t = 0;
function myLoop() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //code below
    console.log(Date() + ' and count is ' + t++);
    //code above
    if (t < 20) {
      myLoop();
    }
  }, i++)
}
myLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `i++` twice in your code. First you increment it when you call `setTimeout` at the bottom of your code and then you display the uneven value via console log and increment `i`. Change your logging to

```
console.log(Date() + ' and count is ' + i);
```